# How can I subscribe on c# stream from python using pythonnet?

Tags: c#, python, python.net, wasapi

I need to analyze loopbackcapture stream with python.

I didn't found any python wrappings for wasapi loopbackcapture, so I had to use c# (in which I don't have any experience).

For now I have c# assembly dll which is wrappings to wasapiLoopbackCapture and records this to the file. But I need to perform analysis on the real time.

```cs
 using (WasapiCapture soundIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture())
        {

            //initialize the soundIn instance
            soundIn.Initialize();

            //create a SoundSource around the the soundIn instance
            SoundInSource soundInSource = new SoundInSource(soundIn) { FillWithZeros = false };

            //create a source, that converts the data provided by the soundInSource to any other format
            IWaveSource convertedSource = soundInSource
                .ChangeSampleRate(sampleRate) // sample rate
                .ToSampleSource()
                .ToWaveSource(bitsPerSample); //bits per sample

            //channels...
            convertedSource = convertedSource.ToMono()

            //create a new wavefile
            WaveWriter waveWriter = new WaveWriter(output_file, convertedSource.WaveFormat)
            //register an event handler for the DataAvailable event of the soundInSource
            soundInSource.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //read data from the converedSource
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[convertedSource.WaveFormat.BytesPerSecond / 2];
                    int read;

                    //keep reading as long as we still get some data
                    while ((read = convertedSource.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        //write the read data to a file
                        waveWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                };
}
```

1) Is it possible to return stream from c# and subscribe on it from python?

2) another variant is to analyze stream on c# side and fire some events to python script. how can I do this? ( I mean event's firing and handling side of thing)

Comment: I guess Instead of events I can use polling